# Windows Phone Negative App getting Credentials from All ready Installed Facebook App in WP

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, facebook-login

I need a Help From You.
I Developing App with Login Credentials of Facebook. Im working with [facebook authentication](http://igrali.com/2012/06/05/facebook-authentication-from-windows-phone-app/) and it's working Properly.

But we want More Easy way.

If already Windows Phone Facebook App is Installed in my Phone, my App must take the Credentials from that FB App to My App.

Can Any One Help Me How can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could refer to below links to achieve your goal.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone

http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/sso/